# NoSuchAlghoritmExeption when you call the java cipher.getinstance()

Tags: java, android

getInstance returns NoSuchAlghoritmExeptoin, although when checked by the operator, one of them is AndroidOpenSSL: Cipher. AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding

```
    Cipher cipher;
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

Answer (score 2):

[NoSuchAlghoritmExeption](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/NoSuchAlgorithmException.html) happens when you don't have that algorithm on your device environment.

Well, the first question here is - why do you need **ECB**?
It has a bunch of disadvantages

Have you tried the **CBC**? It will work probably on all Android environments.
My steps would be next:

- Try to use CBC instead of `EBC`, it also has `PKCS5Padding`, `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING")`
- Verify if the result matches your expectation
- Go through the docs and verify what [algorithms](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher) are supported in Cipher
- Find [libraries](https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption) with support of needed algorithms

Describe your issue in a more detailed way, please.